# xorg display problem - user cannot login

Tags: 12.04, xorg

I was having an error all day. And i emptied the `xorg.conf` in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.
The display now eventually shows the login GUI. (i was expecting that all day)

The problem now is that when I go to login and press enter (in order to log me in) the x server or lightdm restart (my screen goes black shows nvidia for 1 sec and comes again to login GUI).

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted `~/.Xauthority` and then I reinstalled `xorg`. problem solved!

Comment: Also, if its not working either, try to delete /etc/X11/xorg.conf. (just remember to backup)

Answer (score 0):

I found this info on login loop "Ubuntu 13.10 login loop" :
(IN TERMINAL (ctrl-alt-f1)) : sudo mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.backup
(THEN) sudo reboot

This stopped the login loop.